# dividing by 2 and ceiling until remains 1

Tags: math, complexity-theory, logarithm

having the following algorithm only for natural numbers:
rounds(n)={1, if n=1; 1+rounds(ceil(n/2)), else}
so writing in a programming language this will be

```
int rounds(int n){
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    return 1+rounds(ceil(n/2));
}
```

i think this has time complexity O(log n)

is there a better complexity?

Comment: this would be easier to answer if you could describe the _intent_ of the algorithm.  It's clearly going to produce a number related to `log2(n)`, and take ~`log2(n)` iterations to do it.

Comment: oh, ok. for example i have a game that is played at a table with 3-6 players. first round the number of tables will be ceil(number_of_players/6), and next rounds will be made out of the best 3 players from each table. this result in ceil(number_of_tables/2) tables every next round. the question is how many rounds will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by listing the results from 1 upward,

```
rounds(1) = 1
rounds(2) = 1 + rounds(2/2) = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Next, when `ceil(n/2)` is 2, `rounds(n)` will be 3. That's for `n = 3` and `n = 4`.

```
rounds(3) = rounds(4) = 3
```

then, when `ceil(n/2)` is 3 or 4, the result will be 4. `3 <= ceil(n/2) <= 4` happens if and only if `2*3-1 <= n <= 2*4`, so

```
round(5) = ... = rounds(8) = 4
```

Continuing, you can see that

```
rounds(n) = k+2 if 2^k < n <= 2^(k+1)
```

by induction.

You can rewrite that to

```
rounds(n) = 2 + floor(log_2(n-1)) if n > 1 [and rounds(1) = 1]
```

and mathematically, you can also treat `n = 1` uniformly by rewriting it to

```
rounds(n) = 1 + floor(log_2(2*n-1))
```

The last formula has the potential for overflow if you're using fixed-width types, though.

So the question is

- how fast can you compare a number to 1,
- how fast can you subtract 1 from a number,
- how fast can you compute the (floor of the) base-2 logarithm of a positive integer?

For a fixed-width type, thus a bounded range, all these are of course O(1) operations, but then you're probably still interested in making it as efficient as possible, even though computational complexity doesn't enter the game.

For native machine types - which `int` and `long` usually are - comparing and subtracting integers are very fast machine instructions, so the only possibly problematic one is the base-2 logarithm.

Many processors have a machine instruction to count the leading 0-bits in a value of the machine types, and if that is made accessible by the compiler, you will get a very fast implementation of the base-2 logarithm. If not, you can get a faster version than the recursion using [one of the classic bit-hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog).

For example, sufficiently recent versions of gcc and clang have a `__builtin_clz` (resp. `__builtin_clzl` for 64-bit types) that maps to the `bsr*` instruction if that is present on the processor, and presumably a good implementation using some bit-twiddling if it isn't provided by the processor.

The version

```
unsigned rounds(unsigned long n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    return sizeof n * CHAR_BIT + 1 - __builtin_clzl(n-1);
}
```

using the `bsrq` instruction takes (on my box) 0.165 seconds to compute `rounds` for 1 to 100,000,000, the bit-hack

```
unsigned rounds(unsigned n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    --n;
    n |= n >> 1;
    n |= n >> 2;
    n |= n >> 4;
    n |= n >> 8;
    n |= n >> 16;
    n -= (n >> 1) & 0x55555555;
    n = (n & 0x33333333) + ((n >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    n = (n & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((n >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
    return ((n * 0x01010101) >> 24)+1;
}
```

takes 0.626 seconds, and the naive loop

```
unsigned rounds(unsigned n) {
    unsigned r = 1;
    while(n > 1) {
        ++r;
        n = (n+1)/2;
    }
    return r;
}
```

takes 1.865 seconds.

If you don't use a fixed-width type, but arbitrary precision integers, things change a bit. The naive loop (or recursion) still uses `Θ(log n)` steps, but the steps take `Θ(log n)` time (or worse) on average, so overall you have a `Θ(log² n)` algorithm (or worse). Then using the formula above can not only offer an implementation with lower constant factors, but one with lower algorithmic complexity.

- Comparing to 1 can be done in constant time for suitable representations, `O(log n)` is the worst case for reasonable representations.
- Subtracting 1 from a positive integer takes `O(log n)` for reasonable representations.
- Computing the (floor of the) base-2 logarithm can be done in constant time for some representations, and in `O(log n)` for other reasonable representations [if they use a power-of-2 base, which all arbitrary precision libraries I'm semi-familiar with do; if they used a power-of-10 base, that would be different].

Answer (score 1):

If you think of the algorithm as iterative and the numbers as binary, then this function shifts out the lowest bit and increases the number by 1 if it was a 1 that was shifted out. Thus, except for the increment, it counts the number of bits in the number (that is, the position of the highest 1). The increment will eventually increase the result by one, except when the number is of the form 1000.... Thus, you get the number of bits plus one, or the number of bits if the number is a power of two. Depending on your machine model, this might be faster to calculate than O(log n).